# Setup AKS Private Cluster with different API Server IP Address

Tags: azure-aks, azure-cloud-services

My office is planning to use Multi Cluster in AKS Azure.

When i do POC to setup new AKS Azure Private Cluster privisioning with different subnet, the API Server ip address is always set to `10.240.0.4` but the host or api server URL is different (random).

Could i set that API Server IP Address to different IP Address for each cluster with different virtual network ?

FYI, I provision AKS Private Cluster by Azure Portal

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can get something [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters). The API Server of the private AKS cluster uses the Azure private Link service, so it needs to have a private IP address of the subnet that your private AKS cluster in. And all the things have done by Azure, then it gives the first available private IP address of the subnet, then the API Server gets the private IP address `10.240.0.4`. You can change the address space of the subnet that your AKS cluster in, then the API Server will get a different private IP address, but it will still be the first available IP and you can't decide which one.

Comment: can we change API server address of AKS Private Cluster to custom domain ?

Comment: @NickyPuff No, it's an automatically assigned address.